# Setting OpenNFC on AVD?

Tags: android

I have a very simple question. I am trying to enable NFC on Open NFC AVD (emulator). If I go to Settings-Wireless- NFC it does not seem to allow me to check the box. and subsequently the android beam option is disabled. How can I enable NFC on emulator?

I have seen someone was mentioning a separate application on emulator "Setting OpenNFC". Where can I find it? is it not supposed to show up on emulator application list?

I am running android-4.2.1_r1 Open NFC 4.5.2,  Android SDK API level 17.

thanks in advance for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenNFC 4.4.1 instead of 4.5.2. It has a dedicated app pre-installed in emulated device called "Setting OpenNFC" for starting NFC funcionality. The only disadvantage is the lower API Level:/

Answer (score 0):

Or the virtualbox appliance can also be a good solution. Check it here http://open-nfc.org/wp/2013/04/25/new-virtualbox-appliance-embedding-open-nfc-for-android/